# migrating from keras to pytorch

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

i'm newly in pytorch
it is the model with bidirectional lstm, is there any body to tel me what is the equivalent of this two different lstm & bi-lstm model?
i try some torch codes but it do not worked.because this code has suitable acc in keras,i want the exact model in torch and i unfortunately can't find it:(
fist_one:

```
def lstm_model(embedding_size, vocab_size):

    title = layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='title')
    body = layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='body')

    embedding = layers.Embedding(
        mask_zero=True,
        input_dim=vocab_size,
        output_dim=embedding_size,
        weights=[w2v_weights],
        trainable=True
    )

    lstm_1 = layers.LSTM(units=80, return_sequences=True)
    lstm_2 = layers.LSTM(units=80, return_sequences=False)
    emb_title = embedding(title)
    print("question embedding shape", emb_title.shape)
    sum_a = lstm_2(lstm_1(emb_title))
    print("q_output shape", sum_a.shape)

    emb_body = embedding(body)
    print("answer embedding shape", emb_body.shape)

    sum_b = lstm_2(lstm_1(emb_body))
    print("a_output shape", sum_a.shape)

    sim = layers.dot([sum_a, sum_b], axes=1, normalize=True)
    print("qa_similarity shape", sim.shape)

    #     sim = layers.Activation(activation='sigmoid')(sim)
    sim_model = models.Model(
        inputs=[title, body],
        outputs=[sim],
    )
    sim_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    embedding_model = models.Model(
        inputs=[title],
        outputs=[sum_a]
    )
    return sim_model, embedding_model
```

second one:

```
def bilstm_model(embedding_size, vocab_size):
    title = layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='title')
    body = layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='body')

    embedding = layers.Embedding(
        mask_zero=True,
        input_dim=vocab_size,
        output_dim=embedding_size,
        weights=[w2v_weights],
        trainable=True
    )

    lstm_1 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, units=100, return_sequences=True))
    lstm_2 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, units=100, return_sequences=False))
    sum_a = lstm_2(lstm_1(embedding(title)))
    sum_b = lstm_2(lstm_1(embedding(body)))

    sim = layers.dot([sum_a, sum_b], axes=1, normalize=True)
    #     sim = layers.Activation(activation='sigmoid')(sim)
    sim_model = models.Model(
        inputs=[title, body],
        outputs=[sim],
    )
    sim_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    embedding_model = models.Model(
        inputs=[title],
        outputs=[sum_a]
    )
    return sim_model, embedding_model
```

i;m llokingo for true answer in weeks:(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible conversion of your first `lstm_model` to PyTorch

Usually, you create a class for your networks in PyTorch.

Therefore I'll be implementing LSTM using a class

```
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hidden_size, num_layers,
                 dropout, embedding_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=embedding_size,
                                    embedding_dim=vocab_size)
        self.rnn = getattr(nn, 'LSTM')(vocab_size,
                                       hidden_size,
                                       num_layers,
                                       dropout=dropout)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_size,
                                 out_features=embedding_size)
        self.init_weights()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weight_size = (num_layers, vocab_size, hidden_size)

    def init_weights(self):
        init_range = 0.1
        nn.init.uniform_(self.encoder.weight, -init_range,
                         init_range)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.decoder.weight)
        nn.init.uniform_(self.decoder.weight, -init_range,
                         init_range)

    def forward(self, input_, hidden_):
        embedded = self.encoder(input_)
        output, hidden_ = self.rnn(embedded, hidden_)
        decoded = self.decoder(hidden_)
        return F.log_softmax(input=decoded, dim=1), hidden_

    def init_hidden(self):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        return (weight.new_zeros(self.weight_size),
                weight.new_zeros(self.weight_size))
```

Now, if you directly use the network above, you might encounter some problems. In that case, you need to modify the values.

Comment: tnx so  much for your answering,so would you please is this implemetation is truw for that? if not, please help to make this code as exact as the keras code:)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=kwargs["vocab_size"],
                                      embedding_dim=kwargs["embedding_dim"],
                                      padding_idx=kwargs["pad_idx"])
        self.embeddings.weight.requires_grad = True  # to not refine-tune

        if kwargs["model"] == "lstm":
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=kwargs["embedding_dim"],  # input
                                hidden_size=kwargs["lstm_units"],  # output
                                num_layers=kwargs["lstm_layers"],
                                bidirectional=False,
                                batch_first=True)
        if kwargs["model"] == "BiLSTM":
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=kwargs["embedding_dim"],  # input
                                hidden_size=kwargs["bilstm_units"],  # output
                                num_layers=kwargs["bilstm_layers"],
                                bidirectional=True,
                                batch_first=True)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(kwargs["dropout"])
        self.tanh = F.tanh
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(kwargs["dropout"])

    def forward(self):
        pass


class LSTM_Model(Model):
    """
    a class to define multiple models
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def forward(self, question, answer):
        question_embedding = self.embeddings(question)
        # print("question embedding shape:", question_embedding.shape)
        answer_embedding = self.embeddings(answer)
        # print("answer embedding shape:", answer_embedding.shape)
        q_output, (qhidden, qcell) = self.lstm(question_embedding)
        print("q_output shape:", q_output.shape)
        # print("qhidden shape:", qhidden.shape)
        # print("qcell shape:", qcell.shape)
        a_output, (ahidden, acell) = self.lstm(answer_embedding)
        print("a_output shape:", a_output.shape)
        # print("ahidden shape:", ahidden.shape)
        # print("acell shape:", acell.shape)
        # qa_similary = torch.mm(qhidden[-1], ahidden[-1])
        # qa_similary =torch.matmul((qhidden[-1]), torc.th(ahidden[-1]))
        q_output = q_output[-1]
        q_output = q_output.squeeze()
        a_output = a_output[-1]
        a_output = a_output.squeeze()
        mm = torch.mul((q_output), (a_output))
        mm -= mm.min(1, keepdim=True)[0]
        mm /= mm.max(1, keepdim=True)[0]
        qa_similary =torch.mean(mm, dim=1)
        # print("qa_similary shape:", qa_similary.shape)
        return qa_similary, qhidden

    print("**************************MODEL DEFINE & CREATED!****************************")
```

is this a true and completely exact implemetation of that keras code for two layer lstm?